# Swagger-UI Response Content Type

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, http-accept-header

Is it possible to add the Response Content Type select box without creating the Response Class (Status 200) schema?

My web services return JSON or XML format depending on the accept header. I need this dropdown after that.

Answer (score 2):

You can populate the valued for the 'Response Content Type' dropdown with the `produces` property of the Swagger definition:

```yaml
---
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: 0.0.0
  title: Simple API
produces:
  - application/xml
  - application/json
paths:
  /:
    get:
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
```

You'll eventually need to define your response schema as well, but that definition can be independent of the response content type (json vs xml).

Comment: can you please tell me, if my api returns json data so what would be the annotation  for getting xml and json both content type??

Comment: If your API returns json data only, just specify the json line in the 'produces'. If you can produce either json or xml, use the example above.

Comment: In the controller how do you get what response content-type is selected?